# How to handle recurring charge in PayPal checkout

Tags: php, paypal

I have been trying to achieve a PayPal checkout with a subscription option; I can do this with a one-time transaction but no idea how to do with recurring subscription.

```
<script>
paypal.Button.render({
    // Configure environment
    env: '<?php echo $paypal->paypalEnv; ?>',
    client: {
        sandbox: '<?php echo $paypal->paypalClientID; ?>',
        production: '<?php echo $paypal->paypalClientID; ?>'
    },
    // Customize button (optional)
    locale: 'en_US',
    style: {
        size: 'small',
        color: 'gold',
        shape: 'pill',
    },
    // Set up a payment
    payment: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.create({
            transactions: [{
                amount: {
                    total: '1.00',
                    currency: 'USD'
                }
            }]
      });
    },
    // Execute the payment
    onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.execute()
        .then(function () {
            // Show a confirmation message to the buyer
            //window.alert('Thank you for your purchase!');

            // Redirect to the payment process page
            window.location = "process.php?paymentID="+data.paymentID+"&token="+data.paymentToken+"&payerID="+data.payerID+"&pid=<?php echo $productData['id']; ?>";
        });
    }
}, '#paypal-button');
</script>
```

Express checkout with recurring payment.

Comment: Use paypal subscriptions

Comment: @prady00 any reference link?